# Encoding problems in JSP

Tags: jsp, encoding, utf-8, webforms

I have an html-form with several text fields.

When I try to submit not English characters (Russian in my case) server is received "unreadable" string (not questions - "???" but some strange characters).

I simplified my code to show it here:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
  <head><title>Simple jsp page</title></head>
  <body>
    <c:out value="${param.rustext}"/>
    <form action="/test" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="rustext" width="30">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

How should I fix that?

Comment: Are your page headers actually sending UTF-8 as the encoding?  Check with something like Fiddler

Comment: And what should I do if they aren't?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Tomcat uses ISO-8859-1 as the default character encoding for URL parameters, regardless of the encoding of the page that contains the URL. This can be changed with the ["URIEncoding" attribute in its Connector](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/config/http.html) configuration. Other application servers may have similar settings.

[This article](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/joconner/archive/2005/07/charset_traps.html) covers many problems commonly encountered when working with JSP.

Comment: Yes, I use Tomcat. Thanks for the link, I'll try to find something usefull there.

Comment: See http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/config/http.html for the specifics of the URIEncoding attribute.

Comment: This answer is *actually* wrong. The OP was using POST, not GET.

Answer (score 3):

Erickson explained this very well on this page. A server-independent solution is to use a character encoding filter, à la org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter. See example below:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;

public class EncodingFilter implements Filter {
    private String encoding = "utf-8";
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
            FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        request.setCharacterEncoding(encoding);
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
        String encodingParam = filterConfig.getInitParameter("encoding");
        if (encodingParam != null) {
            encoding = encodingParam;
        }
    }
    public void destroy() {
        // nothing todo
    }
}
```

In web.xml add the filter declaration and the filter url mapping in the appropriate sections:

```
  <filter>
  <filter-name>EncodingFilter</filter-name>
  <description>
    <![CDATA[Changes the encoding of the request, in order to help the appserver to correctly interpret request params]]>
  </description>
  <filter-class>com.mypackage.EncodingFilter</filter-class>  
 <init-param>
    <param-name>encoding</param-name>
    <param-value>ISO-8859-15</param-value>
  </init-param>   
</filter>


  <filter-mapping>
      <filter-name>EncodingFilter</filter-name>
      <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
```

Comment: Note that this only covers the request body, not the request URL. In other words: this will set encoding for POST requests, not for GET requests. For GET requests you still need to fiddle with the servletcontainer's config, as outlined in Erickson's answer.

Comment: Right, I haven't thought about the URL.

Answer (score 0):

When using POST - which is a must tu use encoding - the form is send as content-type "application/x-www-form-urlencoded". You may specify the form-attribute accept-charset="UTF-8" to specify your encoding.

Answer (score 0):

This is the same as Victor Ionescu proposed, but you don't need to write your own encoding filter.

Add the following filter to web.xml

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>charsetFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>encoding</param-name>
        <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>charsetFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>*.admin</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```