# Multipart form in JSP, encoding problems in Glassfish

Tags: jsp, servlets, character-encoding, glassfish, multipartform-data

I'm getting invalid character from my jsp/servlet using Eclipse and Glassfish.

If I enter "Pêche" I get "PÃªches". So, this is encoding problem. I tried several thinks and nothing works.

- I tried to add a filter ([Encoding problems in JSP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/932559/encoding-problems-in-jsp))
- I tried to add jsp properties in web.xml ([Unable to change charset from ISO-8859-1 to UTF-8 in glassfish 3.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6279504/unable-to-change-charset-from-iso-8859-1-to-utf-8-in-glassfish-3-1))
- I tried to change the character encoding my self in java code by request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
- I tried to add VM arguments ([Unable to change charset from ISO-8859-1 to UTF-8 in glassfish 3.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6279504/unable-to-change-charset-from-iso-8859-1-to-utf-8-in-glassfish-3-1)) but I cannot because of this ([Eclipse - No server found in Run Configurations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11144068/eclipse-no-server-found-in-run-configurations))
- I added this " accept="UTF-8" accept-charset="UTF-8"  " to my
- I added `<parameter-encoding default-charset="UTF-8"/>` in sun-web.xml and glassfish-web.xml

I still get Mojibake.

Here is my servlet code:

```
String name = (String) request.getParameter("templateName");
```

Here is my jsp content:

```
<%@ page pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>....</title>
</head>
<body>
     <form action="<c:url value="/form/edit" />" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

                <input type="text" id="templateName" name="templateName"  />
                <br />

                <input type="submit" value="Valider" class="button button_blue margin_button_form"/>
        </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Any other suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the end, it seems to be a Glassfish bug: https://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-18516

Solved awfully with this: `new String (s.getBytes ("iso-8859-1"), "UTF-8");` (https://stackoverflow.com/a/549634/1458542)

Answer (score 1):

I just faced the same issue. I guess you can temporarily set this in glassfish-web.xml:

```
<parameter-encoding default-charset="UTF-8"></parameter-encoding>
```

This works for me.

Comment: Solved it by this.... WEB-INF\glassfish-web.xml with content
<glassfish-web-app>
 <parameter-encoding default-charset="UTF-8"></parameter-encoding>
</glassfish-web-app>

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
</head>
```

And in your Servlet add this:

```
request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
response.setContentType("text/html; charset=UTF-8");
```

Comment: Not working, I still get strange characters. Thanks any way ;) Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

http://www.devsniper.com/glassfish-tips-default-encoding/

Furthermore test POST and GET forms as they are handled differently. The accept attribute is informative to the browser too. (Not getting HTML entities for instance.)

Comment: I tried to add this<parameter-encoding default-charset=”UTF-8″/>

Comment: I added "<parameter-encoding default-charset="UTF-8"/>" in sun-web.xml and glassfish-web.xml and still not working...

Comment: If no one gives a helpful answer, disable some servlet filters, or better yet create a new test project. :( sorry