# java.io.IOException: Corrupt form data: no leading boundary

Tags: java, utf-8, character-encoding, glassfish, boundary

I'm currently working on a web app using **glassfish 4 / Java EE 7**. I had an encoding problem : Glassfish default is **ISO-8859-15** and I need **UTF-8**. Sometimes I had some weird characters but no problem with the web app working fine. 
So, I changed one line un my **glassfish-web.xml** file, I added 
    `<parameter-encoding default-charset="UTF-8"/>`

Then I changed in my JSP files `<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>`
instead of
    `<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-15"%>`

Now I don't have those weird characters anymore, but since then, I have problems with POST requests when the content-type is **multipart/form-data**

I get an error 500, and when I look in glassfish log, I see this exception :

> java.io.IOException: Corrupt form data: no leading boundary: ------WebKitFormBoundaryCgZXcxucgAjYv0sU != ------WebKitFormBoundaryCgZXcxucgAjYv0sU;charset=UTF-8

So I printed the request headers and I saw :

> Header [content-type] : multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryCgZXcxucgAjYv0sU;charset=UTF-8

It looks like it added the charset at the end of the content-type header (why not ?) but it seems to look for the wrong boundary

> WebKitFormBoundaryCgZXcxucgAjYv0sU;**charset=UTF-8**

Obviously, I tried to remove the UTF-8 line from my glassfih-web.xml file, but it doesn't help.

Does anyone know why there is the charset in the boundary and/or how to get rid of it or how to handle it ?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Did you check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16563233/2083770)?

Comment: Thanks for such a fast answer. I saw this post, but I didn't find my boundary issue.

Comment: My fault, I thought it could help you. But perhaps this could help you [The fileupload Example Application](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/servlets016.htm)?